# Trouble instantiate BiPRO SOAP Client

Tags: web-services, maven, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I'm facing some trouble during create a SOAP client. 
I have to use a BiPRO WebService (a normative communication pattern beween German insurance agencies).
That WebService has got a complex Datastructure and I think that the code generator has some problems with that structure.

I get following error message:

```
SAXParseException; [...] A class/interface with the same name "barmenia.LebenWs.CTElementarprodukt" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
```

and following

```
[...] (Relevant to above error) another "CTElementarprodukt" is generated from here
```

After some research I figured out that using

```
autoNameResolution
```

would help. But if I do so, the classes are not generated correct (some properties are missing - that one the message above claimes about).

I'm using following maven plugin to generate the client:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>de.tj.msc.bipro.consumer.taa.tarifierung.services.clients.leben.barmenia.LebenWs</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>
                            https://ws0.barmenia24.de/ibis/services/lebenservice_2.1.5.1.2?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I read something about using a xjb file.
But I do not have such a file.

It would be great if anybody could help me.
Thank you very much !

Best wishes

Comment: Did you try to use a different JAX-WS/JAX-B generating library to check if you got the same errors (like the [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/) )?

Comment: Yes - using this plugin fixed the problem

Comment: Nice! So should I write this as regular answer?

Comment: Sure - lets mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, I would suggest to use a different JAX-WS/JAX-B generating library to check if you get the same errors - like the [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/), which is working perfectly fine in my projects (see the [cxf-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter) for example).